# Komascript style for empty page after page with `\part` title, or how to get page numbers there cleanly

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, koma-script

My question is very similar to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26604/8141), and solutions there might work, but I'm using KOMA-script.  I'd like page numbers on every page, including empty ones.  To this end, I passed `cleardoublepage=plain` as an argument to the `scrbook` class.  This has the intended effect for empty pages introduced before `\chapter`, but not for empty pages introduced after `\part`.

```
\documentclass[cleardoublepage=plain]{scrbook}
\begin{document}
\part{One}
\chapter{One-A}
Hello
\chapter{Two-A}
Hello
\end{document}
```

Several solutions are offered in the linked question, but all seem rather hackish to me, boiling down to a temporary redefinition of `\empty`.  Is there a KOMA-script specific solution?  `\partpagestyle` defines the *Page style for the pages with `\part` titles.* (KOMA-script 2012-07-22 user manual, page 71).  Is there a KOMA-script way to define the page style for the empty page *after* the page  with the `\part` title?

Comment: With `scrbook` the correct patch is `\patchcmd{\partheademptypage}{empty}{plain}{}{}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `scrbook` the possible creation of the empty page following a part starting page is handed to the command `\partheademptypage` whose definition is

```
\newcommand*{\partheademptypage}{%
  \if@twoside\if@openright
      \null%
      \thispagestyle{empty}%
      \newpage
  \fi\fi
}
```

So you have two choices: either `\renewcommand` or a simpler patch:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\partheademptypage}{empty}{plain}{}{}
```

(use the page style you prefer instead of `plain`).

Caveat. I firmly believe that otherwise empty pages should have nothing at all in them. The page number is irrelevant, for them.

Comment: I want a page number even on otherwise empty pages, because for me, a page number does not only serve as an anchor for the same page, but also assists when a reader is looking for a particular page number.  When I'm browsing looking for page 16, and pages 14 and 18 are empty without any page numbers, that could make it a little bit more involved to find page 16.

Comment: I added [this related question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/136146/8141).

Comment: @gerrit If a page is empty, it's because in the facing page a chapter starts and so the page is numbered.

Comment: so simple with `etoolbox`. Define a new desired pagestyle and bingo!!! thanks a lot!!!

Comment: `\renewcommand*{\partheademptypage}{}` was the way to go for me so that the page was treated like a normal page in `scrbook`. Any dangers you see here? I visually checked the outcome and at least that is was I desired.

Comment: @mkastner That's quite drastic.

Comment: @egreg because chapters are on a left page by default (as are parts), the page will be left empty anyways as far as I understand. At least in my specific configuration it works.